# How to deploy from a subdirectory on Github

Tags: github, rstudio, slidify

I am a newbie as far as Git is concerned, so pardon the ignorance. I am using R to make presentations using `slidify`. I have successfully pushed my project to my Github repository from RStudio https://github.com/dhirajkhanna/Training. However, I get a 404 File not found when I try to launch the page (http://dhirajkhanna.github.io/Training/MarketBasket). I have another index.html in a separate repo called slicndice which I am able to see as a page by going to http://dhirajkhanna.github.io/slicndice

I tried doing [this](https://gist.github.com/cobyism/4730490) but no joy. Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 0):

I see MarketBasket on your [master branch](https://github.com/dhirajkhanna/Training/tree/master/MarketBasket); it should be in your `gh-pages` branch to be accessible from dhirajkhanna.github.io

This contrasts with [`dhirajkhanna/slicndice`](https://github.com/dhirajkhanna/slicndice), which has its content in `gh-pages` branch.
As  a result, http://dhirajkhanna.github.io/slicndice does work.

---

Update August 2016: **[Simpler GitHub Pages publishing](https://github.com/blog/2228-simpler-github-pages-publishing)** now allows to keep your page files in a subfolder of the *same* branch (no more `gh-pages` needed):

[image: Now you can select a source in your repository settings and GitHub Pages will look for your content there.]

So now, that content could be in a subfolder of your main branch.

Comment: thanks for the reply. So that means I'll have to create a gh-pages branch? And that would have to be done for all subsequent folders within Training?

Comment: @Dhiraj you already have a gh-pages branch: https://github.com/dhirajkhanna/Training/tree/gh-pages. You need to put in it whatever you want to be visible when you access it with http://dhirajkhanna.github.io/Training/xxx)